# Ldap configuration on gitlab error :Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials for username"

Tags: authentication, ldap, credentials, gitlab, openldap

I have an issue when I try to connect my LDAP to Gitlab:

*Could not authenticate you from Ldapmain because "Invalid credentials for username.*

This is my file conf /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb :

```
  gitlab_rails['ldap_enabled'] = true
    gitlab_rails['ldap_servers'] = {
    'main' => {
      'label' => 'GitLab LDAP',
      'host' =>  '<my domain>',
      'port' => 389,
      'uid' => 'uid',
      'encryption' => 'plain',
      'bind_dn' => 'CN=admin,DC=gitlab,DC=com',
      'password' => 'secret',
      'base' => 'OU=users,DC=gitlab,DC=com',
      'block_auto_created_users' => false,
      'allow_username_or_email_login' =>  true

        }
    }
```

From the command line, when I run:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:ldap:check
```

I can see all my users.

However, when I try to connect on the Gitlab UI, I get the error mentioned above and I'm sure that the password match.

Here's my log file for reference:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>" ^ ^ ", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "username"=>"username", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Redirected to http://mydomain/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem, 
I didn't gave the permission necessary to the users in my ldap (/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif), and this create an error when i wanted to connect on my Gitlab !